# loop some of the steps in jbehave stories

Tags: jbehave

I am writing jbehave stories, inside which there are multiple steps, I want some of the steps inside that story to loop based on the response in previous step. Is there any way to perform this?

Story : -

1. Given picker with picker code  logins
2. When get picklist for picker
3. Then get containers for picker
4. And get Unused container
5. And set container  busy for picker  and batch
6. And update item  picked up by picker  with pick list  container  quantity  storage
7. And get stock control items for picker
8. And get transit area containers for picker
9. And picker  handover container  to QC area

after 2nd step i want step 3-6 to be loop based on response of 2nd step then store the data got from response of step 3-6 in step 9.

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no looping mechanism in the Gherkin syntax that JBehave uses to my knowledge.  The only work-around would be to use parameters like examples tables, but I don't know how to re-write your story to quite accomplish what you'd need, even with that method.  Any looping would need to be done in the step methods themselves.

Comment: examples tables enforces the complete story to re run so this won't fulfil my requirement